# get the IP address as string or null value

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am developing a server application using NestJS.

I would like to get the client IP address, since the client is behind a proxy server, I get its IP by:

```
const theIp = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
```

But the return type of `theIp` above is `string | string[] | undefined`.

I would like to have the IP address to be either `string` value or `null`.  What is the correct way to do it?  What I tried is :

```
const clientIP = theIP? (theIp.length > 0? theIp[0]: null) : null;
```

But I am not sure whether the final result is reliable. Any better way to get client IP address as either a string or null? Or is my solution already good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work as you expect if a string is returned because both `string` and `string[]` have a property length.

A better way is to use `typeof`:

```
const clientIP = typeof theIp === 'string' ? theIp : theIp?.length > 0 ? theIp[0] : null;
```

**EDIT as requested with ES2015 syntax** (it's possible to write a one-liner but imbricating more than 2 ternary operations is so difficult to read and debug that I prefer to write a function):

```
function getClientIp(theIp) {
  if (typeof theIp === 'string') return theIp;
  if (theIp === undefined || theIp.length <= 0) return null;
  return theIp[0];
}
```

Note that next time, you can easily test how your code behaves by yourself without posting a question on SO :)

```
function getClientIp(theIp) {
  return typeof theIp === 'string'
    ? theIp
    : theIp?.length > 0
    ? theIp[0]
    : null;
}

console.log(getClientIp('192.0.0.1')); // 192.0.0.1
console.log(getClientIp(['192.0.0.1'])); // 192.0.0.1
console.log(getClientIp([])); // null
console.log(getClientIp(undefined)); // null
```

Comment: Thanks, your code yields compiler error at `theIp?.length` because it could also be `undefined`, the compiler complains that.  I thought the `?` should be fine but complier is not happy. Could you please double check?

Comment: The `?` is the syntax for optional chaining introduced in ES2020 to ease the management of possibly undefined values ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)). Which version of ECMAScript are you using?

Comment: my project tsconfig is configured using es2015 , is that the reason why the `?` still yields error?  If so, could you please update your answer for es2015?

Comment: @user842225, here you go :)